# CD Laravel Maintenance Mode Fails when missing dependency file

Tags: php, laravel-5, continuous-integration, laravel-5.4, continuous-deployment

I'm working with [CircleCi](https://circleci.com/) (a great continuos integration and delivery platform).
In my configuration file for the deployment job I have the following process.

1. Enable Maintenance Mode
   `php artisan down --message="Update in progress" --retry=30`
2. Checkout Branch
3. Install Dependencies
4. Webpack Compilation
5. Run Migrations
6. Disable Maintenance Mode
   `php artisan up`

The idea is that enabling maintenance mode fist, if some step fails then the application stays down. But I faced that I can´t setup maintenance mode when missing dependencies. I'm getting this:

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
  Class 'Spatie\GoogleCalendar\GoogleCalendarServiceProvider' not found
```

So why I can't set maintenance when some provider (that has nothing to do with this) is not found. Has not sense to me.
Is out there any workaround to this? Like setting up the mode without running the artisan command? Should I report it to the framework contributors? Or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, sorry my fault